# Poisson Brackets in inhomogenous magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

This question came in my classical mechanics paper and I still can’t solve it.

> A particle of mass $m$ and electric charge $e$ is moving under the influence of an inhomogeneous magnetic field $\vec{B}$ with a velocity $\vec{v}$. If $v_i$ denotes speed of the $i$-th component then show that Poisson Bracket of $v_i$ and $v_j$ is proportional to $\frac{e}{m^2}\varepsilon_{ijk}$$B_k$.